# How to implement exact matching on some variables and nearest-neighbor or optimal matching on others?

Tags: r, matching

I have a group of patients that I want to match on a number of variables: age, sex, BMI in category (5 categories), year and comorbidity score.
In order to be computationnaly efficient I'd like to do an exact matching on `year`, `sex` and `BMI category`, then nearest neighbor matching or optimal matching on the other 2 variables (`age` and `comorbidity score`). Does anyone have an idea of how to implement this with matchit or another package? or do I have to do my NN matching on each stratum separately?

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/562444/116195) and [on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69624550/6348551) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963544/6348551) and is explained in the `MatchIt` [documentation](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/reference/matchit.html#examples) (example 2).